# Feed showing only one question

Tags: bug, ios-app

I'm not sure if it's a bug, but the app is showing only one question in the feed.

I hope it isn't much of a bother...

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

#### Screenshot

[image]

I see a comment now saying that it's because I don't have any sites on Stack Exchange yet and am adding images showing the contrary:

[image]

Plus whenever I refresh a question from another one of my added sites pops up.

Comment: Any proof screenshots?

Comment: @alexolut added

Comment: Try to scroll horizontally.

Comment: @alexolut scrolling horizontally doesnt do anything